# Retrieving Facebook Wall posts with Facebook SDK on C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I've seen a couple of similar things but could not find what I was looking for, I am trying to retrieve wallposts, (like 10 last posts) using Facebook SDK, but so far all I could find is how to post on a wall or hove to log in and get public user data.

This is what I have so far code vise:

```
public void facebookClientSetup()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("WOOO STUFF is happening!");
        var fbclient = new FacebookClient("Token|secret");
        dynamic me = fbclient.Get("/me/feed");

        foreach (dynamic post in me.data)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(post.from.name);
        }
    }
```

I have this but it doesnt seem to quite do it.

Am I missing something?
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Could you post the response you get from `fbclient.Get("/me/feed");`, or what exactly is not working?

Comment: firstly, I am not sure what I am supposed to get, I am assuming a string. but I never get anything back, just nothing.

Also, if by response you mean the json feedback that I am supposed to get from /me/feed?auth_token=token|secret (or something like that) what I got was an empty file, a 28byte file only with a blank sturcture.

Comment: @user2946405 have you tried just doing `dynamic me = fbclient.Get("me");` to see if it returns anything?

Comment: @DROP TABLE users I just did and the program breaks with this: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ReBiscuit.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: FYI I just renamed myself, I am user2946405

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as follows...hopefully it helps

```
class Posts
{
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public string PostStory { get; set; }
    public string PostMessage { get; set; }
    public string PostPicture { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}

 try
        {
//all the posts and their information (like pictures and links) is strored in result.data


            var client = new FacebookClient(token);
            dynamic result = client.Get("/me/posts");
            List<Posts> postsList = new List<Posts>();

            for (int i = 0; i < result.data.Count; i++)
            {
                Posts posts = new Posts();

                posts.PostId = result.data[i].id;
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(result.data[i].story, null))
                    posts.PostStory = "this story is null";
                else
                    posts.PostStory = result.data[i].story;
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(result.data[i].message, null))
                    posts.PostMessage = "this message is null";
                else
                    posts.PostMessage = result.data[i].message;

                posts.PostPicture = result.data[i].picture;
                posts.UserId = result.data[i].from.id;
                posts.UserName = result.data[i].from.name;

                postsList.Add(posts);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

if you want advanced options can tray FQL
[Here](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL:stream)
and
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Comment: I want not ***me***, another user (a **friend** or public wall of a  user)